# Is it grammatical/idiomatic to say "[number] [objects] of [person]?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

In other words, is it grammatical/idiomatic to say:

*200 Lies of Luke* (as opposed to: *Luke's 200 Lies*)?

*500 Eggs of Erica the Chicken* (as opposed to: *The 500 Eggs of Erica the Chicken*)?

Just like they did in the title of the movie: 500 Days of Summer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct but the meaning changes because of the lack of the definitive article `The`

The title

*200 Lies of Luke*

would be a list of some of the possibly more than 200 lies, whereas

*Luke's 200 lies* - same meaning as *The 200 lies of Luke*

would be a likely complete list of 200 lies told by Luke

Note: *Summer's 500 days*, would be ambiguous - Summer could be a girl's name and one summer does not have 500 days

Comment: Thanks. But I'm confused. How come 200 Lies of Luke can mean more than 200 lies?

Comment: Because of the lack of `The` the definitive article (look it up)

Comment: Oh, I see. So *200 Lies of Luke* it's the same as *200 Lies by Luke*?

Comment: Hmm, I would not use `by` but I guess yes.

Comment: What would you use instead of "by"?

Comment: To use by I would use _200 lies told by Luke_